# Should this profile description be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, user-accounts, profile-page

[This is the user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/26988/python-student). (I don't think whether this can be discussed here).

He's quite offensive (if he doesn't like the rules, he can always go to Yahoo answers or any other forum).

Comment: Well, I can presume that mods would edit his `about-me` and also take the case to the team. And, I don't think it's a bad thing to discuss about someone who annoys everyone ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removed, and thank you for bringing that to our attention. You could also have flagged any of the user's posts and used the custom reason to explain the problem.

Comment: Are these type of questions once solved, closed?

Comment: @jinawee This Meta question? No, you accept the answer and the moderator usually adds the `status-completed` tag.